# Nginx: filter characters from URI

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I try to redirect some URLS with Nginx but having problems to combine filtering and stripping.
Redirect:

```
location ~* "^/7_skin/skin_archi/skin_control/text_box$" { 
    if ($request_uri ~* "([^/]*$)" ) {
        set  $last_path_component $1; 
    } 
    return 301 https://www.domain.com/wiki/display/$last_path_component; 
}
```

this works fine and filters every path but last. Now I would like to strip characters (- and _) from $last_path_component but that doesn't seem to work.

I tried something like: `rewrite ^(.*)[-_](.*)$ $1$2 permanent;` 
which worked, but not in conjunction with first filter as the whole path is given out.